# How to Find Latency of Other Connected Device via TCP Socket in IOS

Tags: ios, networking

is sending a message to the device which is connected via TCP Socket and calculate the time it takes to reply is the right approach?

Comment: That certainly would be a valid approach but is heavily depending on your exact mission. The common way to check for latency is using [ICMP packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) - that however is handled on the OS/Network stack itself and does not really involve the application layer. Are you trying to benchmark the connection for a specific purpose?

Comment: no. My application connects with several other devices on tcp. i want to show signal strength for all of them in app. there is no benchmarking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common implementation for checking networking latency is based on ICMP packages and is called `ping`.
There is a nice and easy [sample available from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SimplePing/Introduction/Intro.html).

Please note that even though the sample is provided for OSX, it should build and work fine on iOS as well.

Here are some additions I just found: [splinter.com.au/how-to-ping-a-server-in-objective-c-iphone](http://www.splinter.com.au/how-to-ping-a-server-in-objective-c-iphone/)

I would go with `ping` as that way you would not have to build the "echoing" part yourself, that part is done by the remote system/network-stack.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... i have seen that sample before but i think implementation using the method i mentioned would be better for local network connections.